# Link Server using mirroring

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, mirroring

I need to configure a SQL Server 2008R2 link server that goes to one database which is principal and has a mirror failover database. For example I'm in server A that needs to perform a query in server B and in case of failover goes to server C. I create a link server named MyLinkS

I'm trying to configure the link server using this connection string:

```
Server=B;Failover Partner=C;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True;
```

When I'm in server A I'm doing this query:

```
Select Name from [MyLinkS].[MyDatabase].[dbo].[MyTable] where Name = 'Jhon'
```

When Server B is Principal, the query works, but when I change to be the mirror, it doesn't work, it said that "It is in the middle of a restore".

How can I use the same query as before using one or the other server depending if B is principal or mirror?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will work for you:

1. Create `SYNONYM` for table on server B.
2. Create another `SYNONYM` for table on server C.
3. Use `TRY/CATCH` for your select - select from B in `TRY` block and select from C in `CATCH` block.